# Are the events from Frank Herbert's "Destination Void" and "Dune" meant to be in the same universe

Tags: dune, frank-herbert

It's a bit of a stretch, I know, but there are a few clues.

First, the point of "Destination Void" is to create AI, which turns out to be

> somewhat godlike

AI has been outlawed in the "Dune" universe after the Butlerian Jihad, probably for this very reason.

Second, one of the characters in "Destination Void" has an experience of enhanced consciousness in which her mind acts like a supercomputer, a clear parallel with the Mentats from Dune.

Third, there are several references to the "axlotl" tanks in which clones are grown, a term which is also used in various places in the "Dune" series in reference to the Bene Tleilax who also grow clones.

It's possibly that Herbert just likes reusing these concepts, but it seemed strongly suggestive that he meant these to be on the same timeline, albeit Dune happens many thousands of years later.

(Side note: I've never read -- nor do I intend to read -- the "Dune"-related books written by Herbert's son, and don't consider them canon)